# Downloading canvas with border sytle

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I want to download canvas with border. On screen Canvas has border but when I download canvas, its border doesnt appear

```
let canvas=qrRef.current.querySelector("canvas")
canvas.style.border="black 30px solid"
 if(type=="PNG"){
    let image=canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
    let anchor=document.createElement("a");
    anchor.href=image;
    anchor.download=`qr-pollective.png`
    document.body.appendChild(anchor);
    anchor.click()
    document.body.removeChild(anchor)
}
```

console.log(canvas)

```
<canvas height="400" width="400" style="border: 30px solid black; border-radius: 5px; border-collapse: collapse;">
```

Comment: Just render the border in the canvas? You can't "download" css styles

Comment: I  should download with border. How can I do that?

Comment: I just told you, render the border onto the canvas, don't style it with css

Comment: I understood. I mean Do you have any idea to render border ?

Comment: You just need to draw four black rectangles onto the canvas, and when you draw the image draw it smaller and offset by the width of the border.

Comment: If you need more help could you show us the code that draws onto the canvas (or is that in a library that is creating the qr code without a black border?)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a bigger canvas which has space for the black border.

Then copy the canvas you have created onto this bigger one, offset by 30px to make room for the border.

Then draw the 4 black rectangles that make up the border. This bigger canvas is then the one that you want to download.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const biggerCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const w = canvas.width + 60;
const h = canvas.height + 60;
biggerCanvas.width = w;
biggerCanvas.height = h;
const ctx = biggerCanvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(canvas, 30, 30);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0, 0, w, 30);
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fill();
ctx.rect(0, 0, 30, h);
ctx.fill();
ctx.rect(w - 30, 0, w - 30, h);
ctx.fill();
ctx.rect(0, h - 30, w, h);
ctx.fill();
document.body.append(biggerCanvas); //just to show it has drawn the border
```

```html
<canvas height="400" width="400" style="border: 30px solid black; border-radius: 5px; border-collapse: collapse;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with html2canvas here is my code

```
html2canvas(canvas,{backgroundColor: "transparent"}).then(function (canvas) {
           var myImage = canvas.toDataURL();
           downloadURI(myImage, `qr-pollective.png`);
});

function downloadURI(uri, name) {
      var link = document.createElement("a");
   
      link.download = name;
      link.href = uri;
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();   

    }
```